# Display product custom field via "woocommerce_email_order_meta" hook in WooCommerce admin email notification

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, email-notifications

My products have a custom field called **depot**. I need to display this field only in admin mail notifications, not to the customer order recap or customer mail notifications.

I use this code to retrieve the custom field in email notifications :

```
  add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', 'add_depot', 10, 3 );
  
  function add_depot( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text ){
    $items = $order->get_items();

     foreach ( $items as $item ){
       $depot = $item->get_meta('depot');
       $item['name'] = 'Dépôt: ' . $depot . $item['name'];
     }
  }
```

At the moment, it displays the field **only** in customer emails and **not** in admin emails as I would like. I think I need to use **$sent_to_admin** but I'm not sure how.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `woocommerce_email_order_meta` hook has 4 arguments, via `$email->id` you can target specific email notifications

So you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_email_order_meta( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    // Targetting specific email notifications
    $email_ids = array( 'new_order' );
    
    // Checks if a value exists in an array
    if ( in_array( $email->id, $email_ids ) ) {
        // Get items
        $items = $order->get_items();

        // Loop trough
        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
            // Get meta
            $depot = $item->get_meta( 'depot' );

            // NOT empty
            if ( ! empty ( $depot ) ) {
               echo '<p style="color:green;font-size:50px;">Dépôt: ' . $depot . ' - ' . $item->get_name() . '</p>';
            } else {
               echo '<p style="color:red;font-size:50px;">Data not found!</p>';
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', 'action_woocommerce_email_order_meta', 10, 4 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this hook:

```php
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );
```

If you see, the second parameter which you get in arguments is - sent to admin. So if that is true, then you can add your custom meta.

Let me know if that helps.